# PHPs move_uploaded_file does not respect setgid

Tags: php, file-upload

I've moving completed uploads with the function `move_uploaded_file`. I have noticed this does not respect the target directory's setgid bit and has what the file originally had. (I learnt this is Linux behaviour).

What is a good solution to the problem? I thought about loading the file into PHP and resaving it, but the files can be quite big 50MB+ which means more memory usage for PHP.

Comment: You could try calling a shell script form php with `shell_exec` to invoke the move. If you are trying to get it to be the webservice gid, then instead of doing mv, do a `cat` in the shell script and write it into a new file then just `unlink` the old one. If you want it a different one, you would need to do an `su -`, but this might require a bit more work then just that.

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not have access to the `system` call, but a `system("cp")` or even an explicit `chgrp` might do what you want, as far as obeying the setgid bit. You might need to do some sleuthing to get the existing group if it varies from target directory to target directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try PHP's built in [rename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) instead of move_uploaded_file().

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem back in early '13 and fixed it by replacing `move_uploaded_file` with `copy`.
I am not aware of the actual performance and memory impact, but it seems to be irrelevant.